# How do you code something like on facebook you click that profile photo and it will open a dialog box to show that photo?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, photo

Im working a social networking app and Im trying to add something like.. visit a profile and when click the profile photo it will open a dialog box to show that clicked photo..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java:

```
 public void showDialog() {
     final Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create(); // Context, this, etc.
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
     dialog.show();
 }
```

If you are using Kotlin:

```
  public void showDialog() {
      val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context).create(); // Context, this, etc.
      dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
      dialog.show();
  }
```

In your dialog layout, just place an `ImageView` for profile photo

Comment: But I want the current photo to be click that will show in the dialog.. not the obe in the layout